# Land Parcel Numbering Automation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, parcel

I have a parcel data for which I have to give parcel numbering with some suffix defining its landuse.

Is there way to do this in a automation rather than going to each plot and adding attribute manually?

I think in ARCGIS we can achieve that using the Parcel Fabric, but I have a basic License for which I can't use that.

Is there a way we can do this in QGIS or some other method, where we can do this numbering based on some criteria like clockwise and E-W direction?

Answer (score 2):

Really old question, but anyway.
You can do this with ogr2ogr batch scripting or python, but here is the simplest solution I can think of inside QGIS.
[image]
If you are satisfied with the default feature order you can use the fieldcalculator to build a string expression for a new field.

If you want a layer with a different order, one way is to first create a virtual layer with a SQL statement containing ORDER BY, and then use *@row_number* in the fieldcalculator.